# Conditional density of a linear transform of a random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given a random variable $Y \sim D$ and a linear transform $g(Y) = a + bY$, we define a new random variable $W = g(Y)$. The probability density of $W$ is $f_{W}(w) = \cfrac{1}{b}f_{Y}(\cfrac{w-a}{b})$.

However, I am interested in the conditional distribution $f_{W|Y}$. How do I go about finding this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a constant: all probability is attached to $g(Y),$ because once you know $Y,$ you know $W.$

Comment: Thanks @whuber that's my intution as well, but is there a way to show this algebraically. I imagine that it $f_{W|Y}$ should reduce to some realized value of $f_Y$?

Comment: Apply any definition you like.  In any treatment of conditional expectation, one of the first properties proven is called "taking out what is known."  This is demonstrated at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties (without naming it).  Your question is one of the simplest possible examples of this property.

Comment: Thanks @whuber will try to think of way to show this.

Comment: @whuber So is it correct to say $f_{W|Y}(w) = f_{Y}(y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density doesn't exist. One way to show this fact is to start with the conditional cdf of $W$:
\begin{align}
P(W\le w | Y=y) &= P(a+bY \le w | Y=y) \\
&= \mathbf{1}(w \ge a+by)
\end{align}
In other words, the conditional cdf is a step function. It is not differentiable; therefore, the conditional pdf doesn't exist.