# Conditional distribution of product of two random variables given one of the random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say I have two independent random variables $X$, $Y$. Let's define a new random variable $Z = XY$. I know that the distribution of $Z$ follows: $f_{Z}(z) = \int_{-
\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(z/x)\cfrac{1}{|x|}$.

Is it possible to derive the algebraic expression for $f_{Z|Y}$ in terms of $f_{Z}$, $f_{X}$, and/or $f_{Y}$?

Comment: The answer is the same as that to [your previous question:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619578/) take out what is known to conclude that $f_{Z\mid Y=y}$ is the density of $Xy.$

Comment: Thanks again @whuber so if I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that $f_{Z|Y}(z) = f_{X}(z/y)$?

Comment: No, because you have forgotten about the Jacobian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the conditional cdf of $Z|Y$:
\begin{align}
P(Z\le z | Y=y) &= P(XY \le z | Y=y) \\
&= P \left( X \le \frac{z}{y} \right)
\end{align}
Then differentiate to find
$$f_{Z|Y}(z|y) = \frac{1}{y} f_X \left( \frac{z}{y} \right) $$

EDIT: This proof relies on the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are positive. It can be adjusted if this assumption does not hold.

Comment: The derivation is intuitive and the final result is correct. Note, however, that in OP the random variates are implicitly assumed to be continuous, in which case the notation above is slightly sloppy as the conditional probabilities with $Y=y$ are both zero (being Lebesque measure zero). This is just notation though and can be fixed easily.

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos: Which notation do you prefer?